# Android Java time picker listener cannot retrieve hours and minutes for first try

Tags: java, android, timepicker

I'am having trouble from getting the minutes and hours that set by user for my android application. The problem is that when i try to set time in `public void onTimeSet...`  function for the first time, my `btn(hour+":"+minutes)` shows 0:0 but if i try it for the 2nd time, the `btn` able to show the time. I not sure what is the problem or my coding logic is wrong...anyone can help me to trace it?
Here is my code:

```
RelativeLayout rlSun = (RelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.sundayRelativeLayout);
rlSun.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        //openTimePickerDialog(true);
        Calendar currenttime = Calendar.getInstance();

        final TimePickerDialog  timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
                getActivity(), //because this class extends fragment
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                          int minute) {
                        // Get the selected time
                        hour =hourOfDay;
                        minutes = minute;
                    }       
                 }, 
                 currenttime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 
                 currenttime.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 
                 false);
        timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set Time");  
        timePickerDialog.setButton(
              DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE,
              "Set",
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
                          RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.sundayRelativeLayout);
                          Button btn = new Button(getActivity());
                          btn.setText(hour+":"+minutes);
                          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,60);
                          rl.addView(btn,newParams);
                      }
                  }
              });
              timePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,
                  "Cancel",
                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                            if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE){
                                timePickerDialog.cancel();
                            }
                  }
              });
              timePickerDialog.show();
```

Additional information:
I have declared `hour and minutes` outside the class

Comment: I tried to change if i change the code where the button is created in onTimeSet method, yes it works but when user click cancel it still will add the button, what i want is that button will only be created after user click Set in Time picker Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the `hour` and `minutes` variables to the current time before opening the dialog.

Comment: You need to initialize those variables to the current time (not to 0).
`hour = currenttime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);`  
`minutes = currenttime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);`  
Add that before the `timePickerDialog.show();` line.

Comment: I see, i didn't read your comment properly, now the problem is solved! Thanks a million!

Comment: the problem is that in onTimeSet method i'am unable to perform hour = hourOfDay and minutes = minute as i print hour and minutes i get 0:0, and weird thing is that if i set the time for the second time its successfully retrieved. Also i tried your solution it didn't work as i want because its just keep setting current hour and minutes for the button.  So this problem haven't been solved yet.